# Регулярное выражение C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, .net

Здравствуйте. Я впервые столкнулся с регулярными выражениями и возникла проблема.

```
<a\shref=""/здесь ключевое слово/\d+/\S+"">\S+</a></td>
```

Этим выражением я пытаюсь получить все строчки типа

```
<a href="/ключевое слово/цифры, в количестве от 2 (например 39) до 8 (например 12345678)/здесь идет какая то строчка с названием">опять идет какая то строчка с названием </a></td>
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может вот так?

```
<a\shref="/ключевое\sслово/\d+/.+">.+</a></td>
```

Советую скачать себе программу `regex buddy` и тестировать регулярные выражения, очень удобно.

Answer (score 5):

Вытаскивать ссылки лучше не регекспами, а, например, [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
{
   HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
}
```

И дальше уже иметь дело с готовыми строками из href.